# async/await loop array.push issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, for-of-loop

I'm currently working on something where I need to get async data and push it to an array. Please see below.

```
const getStudent = async (id: string) => {
  const student = await fetchSomeData(id); 
  const markedEssayArray: string[] = [];
  
  for await(const essayName of student.essay) {
    const markedEssay = await fetchMarkedEssay(essayName);

    markedEssayArray.push(markedEssay)
  };
 
  student.essay = markedEssayArray;

  return student;
};
```

so basically, I fetch a student, and update the student.essay array with the marked versions. However when I test the code, the student.essay array returns an empty array [].

Could anyone kindly advise where I went wrong?

Comment: remove `await` after `for` => `for(const essayName of student.essay)`

Comment: what is `student.essay` ? array of promise ?

Comment: I’ve tried removing the await after for, but still get the same result unfortunately.                                         To the other question, student.essay is an array of strings

Comment: did you log `markedEssay` in `for..of` loop ? does it print you expected result?

Answer (score 0):

### You can try like this :

```
const getStudent = async (id: string) => {
  const student = await fetchSomeData(id); 
  let markedEssayArray: string[] = [];
  const essayArr = student.essay;

  essayArr.forEach((singleEssay) => {
    let markedEssay = await fetchMarkedEssay(essayName);

    markedEssayArray.push(markedEssay)
  }
   
  student.essay = [...markedEssayArray];

  return student;
};
```